# FIPS County Code Lookup

Tags: python

I'm looking for a library, or some sort of method in Python to return a county name from a [county code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code) such as 48235 which is Irion County, TX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is basically a mapping of county codes to counties.

Getting one is a simple as finding a county list (and Google shall help you in this respect: `www.schooldata.com/pdfs/US_FIPS_Codes.xls`), and translating the data that's in there into a data structure that is suitable to your needs (probably a dictionnary, but you could store it in a DB).

Reading data in this `.xls` file should be pretty using the `xlrd` module, but you could also convert it to `.csv` and use the `csv` module.

Really, what you're looking at is so basic that there is really no need for a library.